# Sometimes rockets don't hit the vehicle

Tags: ps3, battlefield-bad-company-2

There were a few occasions where I tried to hit a vehicle with a rocket, and right when it was about to hit it, it suddenly goes up and misses. Why does it happen?

Comment: What weapon are you experiencing this with? I assume its the RPG or the CG ?

Comment: The first time I'm not sure but I think it was with the RPG-7, the second time it was with the AT4.

Comment: Might sound like a silly question (I dont mean it in an insulting way at all) but are you aware of how the AT4 works ? You have to guide the missle onto the target ... getting shot at the last second could cause the behaviour you are talking about.

Comment: No, I didn't get shot, I could clearly see the rocket going up and missing. In fact I was playing right now and it happened again. I was using the AT4, aiming directly at the vehicle, which was a helicopter in the ground.

Comment: Ow sorry ... in that case I have no idea that's going on. As an alternative you could equip the tracer dart gun and use one of the lock on rocket launchers (RPG or CG) as they rarely miss.

Answer (score 1):

Foliage in Bad Company 2 adversely affects the rockets trajectory.  If you want to experiment with this fire a rocket at a trees leaves.  It both speeds up and goes of in a different direction.  I assume this is a physics glitch of some kind.  It happens when you would least expect it and sometimes there could only be a small obstruction that it hits, almost not visible, and fly's off in the wrong direction.